# How to make netstat on Linux only show OUTBOUND tcp connections?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netstat, ufw

My ubuntu server is infected and there is a process making a bunch of HTTP requests to a bunch of websites (sucks!). I have added the following to my firewall (UFW):

```
sudo ufw deny out proto tcp to any port 1:65535

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
1:65535/tcp                DENY OUT    Anywhere
```

Now I would like to use netstat to list only OUTBOUND tcp connections, not inbound.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want outbound tcp connections, I think you can use

`netstat -atn | tr -s ' '| cut -f5 -d ' ' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'`

That will show all connections whose destination is not your localhost. You can add your internal ip, say

`netstat -atn | tr -s ' '| cut -f5 -d ' ' | grep -v '127.0.0.1\|192.168.0.15'`

Comment: What filters the 'outbound' here? Outbound means only connections INITIATED by an internal process

Answer (score 22):

`netstat -nputw` should do the trick. Add c for continuous updating.

Also, this may be more what you're looking for:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/252179/how-to-inspect-outgoing-http-requests-of-a-single-application